# OroCommerce question, AttachmentExtension migration in OroContactBundle

Tags: orocrm

Bonjour! 
I am getting an error:
`Property Oro\Bundle\ContactBundle\Entity\Contact::$picture does not exist`

I tried to look through possible reasons and I've found a migration in OroContactBundle, there is a migration there:

```
$attachmentExtension->addImageRelation(
            $schema,
            'orocrm_contact',
            'picture',
            [],
            2,
            58,
            58
);
```

Question: I don’t see the picture property in Oro CRM Contact Entity. Is it ok?

Comment: Hi Kacper, please share the full stack trace of an error.

Comment: @AndreyYatsenko: Sure, there are two because one is Runtime and the other one is Reflection Exception.

Comment: @AndreyYatsenko: What is the best to share it? It is too long.

BTW. I think the reflection is good point. It looks like it takes the configuration from db, it finds the "picture" there and tries to render it..

Comment: you can use gist.github.com to share it